# How to remove extra spaces in bash?

Tags: bash, removing-whitespace

How to remove extra spaces in variable `HEAD`?

```
HEAD="    how to  remove    extra        spaces                     "
```

Result:

```
how to remove extra spaces
```

Comment: Do you really want to remove the whitespace in `HEAD`, or just provide the expansion of `$HEAD` without whitespace to another command? The shell provides better tools for controlling the output of expansion than it does tools for just mutating a variable in place.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145981/337382): tr -s " " < file

Answer (score 51):

Try this:

```
echo "$HEAD" | tr -s " "
```

or maybe you want to save it in a variable:

```
NEWHEAD=$(echo "$HEAD" | tr -s " ")
```

**Update**

To remove leading and trailing whitespaces, do this:

```
NEWHEAD=$(echo "$HEAD" | tr -s " ")
NEWHEAD=${NEWHEAD%% }
NEWHEAD=${NEWHEAD## }
```

Comment: Thank. It does not delete the space or at the end or at the beginning of :-(

Comment: couldn't you technically just use `NEWHEAD=${echo $HEAD}`

Comment: You can enable `shopt -s extglob` and then just use `NEWHEAD=${NEWHAED/+( )/ }` to remove internal spaces.

Comment: What's the point of calling `tr` when you don't quote `$HEAD`, so bash does word splitting and therefore collapses the whitespace on itself?

Answer (score 35):

Using awk:

```
$ echo "$HEAD" | awk '$1=$1'
how to remove extra spaces
```

Answer (score 15):

Take advantage of the word-splitting effects of not quoting your variable

```
$ HEAD="    how to  remove    extra        spaces                     "
$ set -- $HEAD
$ HEAD=$*
$ echo ">>>$HEAD<<<"
>>>how to remove extra spaces<<<
```

If you don't want to use the positional paramaters, use an array

```
ary=($HEAD)
HEAD=${ary[@]}
echo "$HEAD"
```

---

One dangerous side-effect of not quoting is that [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) will be in play. So turn it off first, and re-enable it after:

```
$ set -f
$ set -- $HEAD
$ set +f
```

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer. This, or [the answer from kojiro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30066976/1877426).

Comment: Note that the behavior depends on the value `IFS`. With the default `IFS`, namely `$' \t\n'` you'll also replace tabs and newlines by a space.

Answer (score 11):

This horse isn't quite dead yet: Let's keep beating it!*

### Read into array

[Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583095/418413) have mentioned `read`, but since using unquoted expansion may cause undesirable expansions all answers using it can be regarded as more or less the same. [You could do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093896/418413)

```
set -f
read HEAD <<< $HEAD
set +f
```

or you could do

```
read -rd '' -a HEAD <<< "$HEAD"  # Assuming the default IFS
HEAD="${HEAD[*]}"
```

### Extended Globbing with Parameter Expansion

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ HEAD="${HEAD//+( )/ }" HEAD="${HEAD# }" HEAD="${HEAD% }"
$ printf '"%s"\n' "$HEAD"
"how to remove extra spaces"
```

*No horses were actually harmed – this was merely a metaphor for getting six+ diverse answers to a simple question.

Comment: This is the only answer that really makes sense here. It's sad ugly hacks and semi-broken answers are upvoted instead…

Comment: In honor of this answer (which avoids echo, shell expansion and all the other pitfalls all the other answers went into), I deleted my own incorrect answer.

Comment: Two more notes: `read` needs `-r` to prevent processing backslash escapes, and `-d ""` to normalize newlines rather than truncating at first newline. Both options need to be passed before `-a`.

Comment: You introduced an error when applying @MichałGórny's suggestion: `read -rd'' -a HEAD` **will not work**, it needs to be `read -r -d '' -a HEAD` or `read -rd '' -a HEAD`. Also, IFS should be mentioned, as this will only work if `IFS` contains the space character.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would do it with sed:

```
string='    how to  remove    extra        spaces                     '
echo "$string" | sed -e 's/  */ /g' -e 's/^ *\(.*\) *$/\1/'

=> how to remove extra spaces   # (no spaces at beginning or end)
```

The first sed expression replaces any groups of more than 1 space with a single space, and the second expression removes any trailing or leading spaces.

Answer (score 3):

`echo -e "   abc   \t def  "|column -t|tr -s " "`

`column -t` will:

1. remove the spaces at the beginning and at the end of the line
2. convert tabs to spaces

`tr -s " "` will squeeze multiple spaces to single space

---

BTW, to see the whole output you can use `cat - -A`: shows you all spacial characters including tabs and EOL:

`echo -e "   abc   \t def  "|cat - -A`

output: `abc   ^I def  $`

`echo -e "   abc   \t def  "|column -t|tr -s " "|cat - -A`

output:
`abc def$`

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace can take the form of both ***spaces*** and ***tabs***. Although they are *non-printing characters* and unseen to us, `sed` and other tools see them as different forms of whitespace and only operate on what you ask for.  ie, if you tell `sed` to delete x number of ***spaces***, it will do this, but the expression will not match ***tabs***. The inverse is true- supply a ***tab*** to `sed` and it will not match ***spaces***, even if the number of them is equal to those in a ***tab***.

A more extensible solution that will work for removing either/both additional space in the form of ***spaces*** and ***tabs*** (I've tested mixing both in your specimen variable) is:

```
echo $HEAD | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//g'
```

or we can tighten-up @Frontear 's excellent suggestion of using `xargs` *without* the `tr`:

```
echo $HEAD | xargs
```

However, note that `xargs` would also remove newlines.  So if you were to `cat` a file and pipe it to `xargs`, all the extra space- including newlines- are removed and everything put on the same line ;-).

Both of the foregoing achieved your desired result in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
echo '    how to  remove    extra        spaces                     ' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/$ *//g' | sed 's/   */ /g'
```

or

```
HEAD="    how to  remove    extra        spaces                     "
HEAD=$(echo "$HEAD" | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/$ *//g' | sed 's/   */ /g')
```

Answer (score 1):

echo variable without quotes does what you want:

```
HEAD="    how to  remove    extra        spaces      "
echo $HEAD

# or assign to new variable
NEW_HEAD=$(echo $HEAD)
echo $NEW_HEAD
```

output: `how to remove extra spaces`

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of [tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) to remove the extra spaces, and [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to trim the back and front.

```sh
TEXT="     This          is  some                             text   "
echo $(echo $TEXT | tr -s " " | xargs)

# [...]$ This is some text
```