# How to remove consecutive space in shell bash linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have string containing words.

Between the words there is a random number of spaces

```
str="toto1 toto2  toto3   toto4 toto5      toto6"
```

How I can remove duplicated spaces and keep only one space between words?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `tr` with `-s` to squeeze repeated characters:

```
$ echo "$str" | tr -s ' '
toto1 toto2 toto3 toto4 toto5 toto6
```

or

```
$ tr -s ' ' <<< "$str"
toto1 toto2 toto3 toto4 toto5 toto6
```

---

Another funny approach is the one [suggested by glenn hackman here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093896/1983854). As he says,

> Take advantage of the word-splitting effects of not quoting your
>   variable

Example:

```
$ echo "$str"
toto1 toto2  toto3   toto4 toto5      toto6
$ echo $str
toto1 toto2 toto3 toto4 toto5 toto6
```

So you can save the converted string with:

```
new_str=$(echo $str)
```

Comment: The word-splitting hack is only safe if you disable pattern expansion; see kojiro's answer.

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of the linked question?

Answer (score 4):

One of the weird tricks of wordsplitting is how bash puts words back together:

```
$ str="toto1 toto2  toto3   toto4 toto5      toto6"
$ echo $str
toto1 toto2 toto3 toto4 toto5 toto6
```

so…

```
$ str=$(echo $str)
```

If any of your words are globs you'll want to disable globbing, or they'll expand.

```
$ str=$(set -f; echo $str)
```

### Edit:

As Alfe points out, you can still get into trouble if your words start with `-n`, `-e`, or `-E`, which are flags to `echo`. Another solution is to use parameter expansion. As others have pointed out:

```
echo "${str//  / }"
```

is problematic because it will only replace two spaces with one, so if your string is

```
'1   2'
```

the output would only be

```
'1  2'
```

Not what you want. But enter `extglob`, the extra pattern-matching extension to bash:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${foo// / }"
1   2       3
$ echo "${foo//+( )/ }"
1 2 3
```

There you have it. [More on extglob here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob).

Comment: +1 I deleted my own similar answer because I had forgotten about the `-f` option.

Comment: Problematic approach with strings like `-n    foo   bar`.

Comment: That can be worked around using an array: `arr=( $str ); str=$( printf "%s" "${arr[*]}")`. Setting the array removes the whitespace; the `[*]` expansion puts back exactly one space between each element.

Comment: @chepner
Excuse me, you deleted answer `str="toto1 toto2  toto3   toto4 toto5      toto6"
echo ${str//  / }`
?
It worked and i don't understand about `-f option`, could you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: Not my answer, but the problem was that it only replaced runs of exactly two spaces, not two or more.

Comment: @maurelio79 I've addressed that in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/ {2,}/ /g' <<< "$str"
```