# sed command to replace multiple spaces into single spaces

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I tried to replace multiple spaces in a file to single space using sed.

But it splits each and every character like below.
Please let me know what the problem is ...

```
$ cat test.txt
 iiHi Hello   Hi
this   is   loga

$

$ cat test.txt | tr [A-Z] [a-z]|sed -e "s/ */ /g"
 i i h i h e l l o h i
 t h i s i s l o g a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092360/608639)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your `sed` command does the wrong thing because it's matching on "zero or more spaces" which of course happens between each pair of characters!  Instead of `s/ */ /g` you want `s/  */ /g` or `s/ +/ /g`.

Comment: just for clarify, space must be scaped, so it is: `s/\ \ */\ /g` or `s/\ +/\ /g`

Comment: Only if the argument to sed isn't surrounded by quotes

Answer (score 28):

Using `tr`, the `-s` option will squeeze consecutive chars to a single one:

```
tr -s '[:space:]' < test.txt
```

```
 iiHi Hello Hi
this is loga
```

To downcase as well: `tr -s '[:space:]' < test.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Comment: This should have been more upvoted! Never heard of this utility.

Answer (score 12):

```
sed 's/ \+/ /g' test.txt | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

or

```
sed 's/\s\+/ /g' test.txt | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

Good grief that was terse, because `*` matches zero or more it inserted a space after every character, you want `+` which matches one or more. Also I switched the order because in doing so you don't have to `cat` the file.

Comment: sed must be with  '-r', otherwise regexps would not work
`sed -r 's/\s\+/ /g' test.txt`

Comment: @Temak - that must be dependent on the flavor of sed, with GNU sed 4.4 I did not need the flag.

Comment: `$ man sed | grep s\/reg -A1
       s/regexp/replacement/
              Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.  The replacement may contain the special character & to`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` to solve this:

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0);$1=$1}1' test.txt
iihi hello hi
this is loga
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can match the following regex for multiple spaces:

`'\s+'`

and replace with just one space as follows:

`' '`

Comment: This needs the `-E`-flag for extended regexes.