# remove spaces between fields of lines in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

When I do a desc hive table like below on a Linux terminal CLI.

```
hive -e "desc hive_db.hive_table"
```

I get the following output

```
date                string  
entity              string  
key                 int 
id                  string  
direction           string  
indicator           string  
account_number      string  
document_date       string
```

Now I want to redirect the output to a file before doing it I want to remove the spaces between each fields and have just one space between them.

The expected output is below

```
date string 
entity string   
key int 
id string   
direction string    
indicator string    
account_number string   
document_date string
```

I have tried like below

```
hive -e "desc hive_db.hive_table" | tr -s " " > abc.txt
```

The output I get is

```
date    string  
entity  string  
key     int 
id  string  
direction   string  
indicator   string  
account_number  string  
document_date   string
```

Th output I get is a close one but I have `one space and one tab` between each fields in each line

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace multiple spaces with a single space using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50259869/608639), [sed command to replace multiple spaces into single spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22939323/608639), [How to remove extra spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092360/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
hive -e "desc hive_db.hive_table" | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/ /' > abc.txt
```

`[[:space:]]+` matches one or more of any kind of white space (tab, blank, or other including any unicode-defined white space).  `s/[[:space:]]+/ /` replaces that sequence of white space with a single blank.