# extract fields from fixed width file

Tags: cut

I'm trying to extract the two last column of a fixed width file.

Example :

```
 1 Thu Aug 19 21:54:38 2021 125094     4856 PC7C042B7 PTE VC965
 2 Sat Jul 31 04:09:44 2021 174434     4154 PC2C2EF9E PTP VC965
 3 Sat Aug 14 17:19:04 2021 8538286    4070 PCEECA8B2 PTE VC965
```

I want to retrieve two last columns :

PTE VC965
PTP VC965
PTE VC965

i tried this but getting another result :

`cut -d" " -f10,11 < infile`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
cat test.txt | tr -s '[:space:]' | cut -d " " -f 10-11
```

The tr command will reduce several whitespace into a single whitespace. Then the cut command knows how to get the last two fields.

Found the tr command at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22940570/319826