# shell duplicate spaces in file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

Is it possible to remove multiple spaces from a text file and save the changes in the same file using awk or grep?

```
Input example:
aaa     bbb  ccc
   ddd    yyyy

Output I want:
aaa bbb ccc
ddd yyyy
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove extra spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092360/how-to-remove-extra-spaces-in-bash)

Comment: @nuclearwinter27 : `grep` does not modify any file. It reads files and writes to stdout. `awk` programs can create a file, but I am not aware that awk offers anything to update a file in-place; at least it was not designed for this.  Some languages and tools (for instance `sed`, `ruby`, `perl`) make this task easy by simulating "in-place" editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reset value of $1 to again $1  which will allow `OFS` to come into picture and will add proper spaces into lines.

```
awk '{$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned that what if we want to keep only starting spaces then try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/^ +/){
  spaces=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
{
  $1=$1
  $1=spaces $1
  spaces=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: But if i have a text file ,how I can keep the alignment of the beginning of the lines?

Comment: @nuclearwinter27, Please try EDIT solution now and lemme now then?

Comment: @nuclearwinter27, In case of in place editing append ` > temp && mv temp Input_file` to my code. But make sure you run my mentioned command(in my post) to make sure all is coming well on terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
sed -i -E  's#[[:space:]]+# #g' < input file
```

For removing spaces at the start

```
sed -i -E  's#[[:space:]]+# #g; s#^ ##g' < input file
```

Demo:

```
$cat test.txt
aaa     bbb  ccc
   ddd    yyyy

Output I want:
aaa bbb ccc
ddd yyyy
$sed -i -E  's#[[:space:]]+# #g' test.txt 
$cat test.txt
aaa bbb ccc
 ddd yyyy

Output I want:
aaa bbb ccc
ddd yyyy
$
```